# Access Spark History Server Web UI on VM

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spark-webui

I have launched a single node GCP compute engine ( n1-standard-4) and installed spark 3.4.1. How can we view the spark web UI/ spark history server?

I tried to access on chrome browser using http://<compute- engine - instance-ip>:4040. Tried both internal and external IP. Both does not seem to work and getting below message. In addition, how can we verify the correct port used by spark on VM?

- http://<external-ip-of_compute-engine>:4040

  - This site can’t be reached. <external-ip-of_compute-engine> refused to connect
- http://<internal-ip-of_compute-engine>:4040

  - This site can’t be reached. <internal-ip-of_compute-engine> took too long to respond

Comment: after some time 1st option worked, ie connecting to extenal ip.

Comment: could anyone help how to find the port for spark job to use in spark web UI url above ie. where can we see if spark is using 4040?

Comment: You can access it by simply opening http://<driver-node>:4040 in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).
check the official doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#web-interfaces

Comment: Or, you can set `spark.ui.port` yourself when you submit your Spark application.

Comment: thank you. I have few follow up questions to understand more about spark sessions and have posted on separate thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77089332/spark-session-behaviour-using-getorcreate