# Spark session behaviour using getOrCreate()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

According to the Spark documentation, the getOrCreate method, as described in https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.Builder.html#getOrCreate-- , behaves as follows:  getOrCreate Gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one based on the options set in this builder.

Lets assume we have 2 spark applications running in parallel. Application-2 was created after some time post creation of application-1.

Run application-1:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession-1 and run
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-application-1").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",20).getOrCreate()
```

Run application-2: created while application-1 is till running

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-application-2").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",30).getOrCreate()
```

**Query:**

- (1) Does application-2 reuses the spark session already created by application-1?
- (2) At times I have seen spark notifying "WARN SparkSession: Using an existing Spark session; only runtime SQL configurations will take effect".  If "my-application-2" reuses the existing Spark session created by "my-application-1”, what happens to shuffle partitions? Does "session-1" used by "application-2" get updated from 20 to 30, or does "session-1" used by "application-2" ignores the shuffle partition setting of 30 and continue to use 20?

Comment: you have the answers in your question - *getOrCreate Gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one based on the options set in this builder.*

Comment: I can infer that from the doc pointed, 1) in a typical production setup, there will be multiple jobs running parallel, do they reuse existing sessions if available? just curious, is that the recommended practice (2) also what about 2nd part, if we have any application specific configs (such as shuffle partition), do they get ignored when using existing spark sessions and use only existing session configs?

Comment: It is an excellent question. Words are copied by people without  explaining what it really means.

Comment: @Matthew - re: 1, "jobs" for spark are the processing steps that you execute in a session. spark being distributed in nature runs the steps in parallel. the session is started at the beginning of the code. any other `getOrCreate` statements reuse the first one with all specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with spark-shell or notebooks, then the Spark session reuse can occur.

With spark-submit you will always get a new session.

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying. Few followup around the same. (a) what could be the reason for this behaviour where spark-submit always creates new session where as spark-shell or notebook reuse the session? (b) Is it fair to assume that for production use cases, its recommended to always run jobs via spark-submit, so it will always create new session? (c)when spark-shell or notebook reuses existing session, what happens to spark parameters set via config as mentioned above,it gets ignored or existing session reuses new configs ie. shuffle gets updated from 20 to 30 in above case?

Comment: Submitting has no session  it is a JAR that is initiated via cluster or client mode. Non interactive. Spark shell is interactive allowing such constructs.

Comment: thank you. Do you have any thoughts on (b) Is it fair to assume that for production use cases, its recommended to always run jobs via spark-submit, so it will always create new session? (c)when spark-shell or notebook reuses existing session, what happens to spark parameters set via config as mentioned above, it gets ignored or existing session reuses new configs ie. shuffle gets updated from 20 to 30 in above case?

Comment: That is what most do. Or notebooks with databricks.